# Failed to initialize global composer: mac /Sites

Tags: composer-php

Trying to view a local website:

> "Uncaught Error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInite0e6765..etc' not found in /Users/{ username }/Sites/{ sitename }/htdocs/vendor/twig-autoload.php".

So on into Terminal to do `composer dump-autoload`. (It worked the first time I did it).

1. I now get this message:

> "The 'git' command requires command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?" (It asks for Xcode)

I click No.

2. Terminal tells me the file command has been run OK, but no...
3. Repeating the `dump autoload` with `-vvv` reveals the truth:

> Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /Users/{ username }/.composer/composer.json

Searching about, the only things I've found on the composer error seem to be related to Lavarel.

**info:**

- Composer is installed in `/Sites/{ sitename }/vendor/`
- Composer version: 1.10.6

**So what I'd like to understand:**

1. Why is composer trying to initialise a 'global composer'? Does it think the locally installed one is global, or could there be another Composer it's trying to default to?
2. How do I tell composer where the json file is?
3. What should I do about the xCode message, if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled composer (and Twig - the only package I'm using - seems overkill for one package, but trying out alternatives didn't end well).

The site is now back running (locally).

Still have the issue of xCode request from Terminal, but that's for another question.

**So the answer seems to be: Reinstall composer and packages.**